# Loop through all files in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, sh

```
FILES="$DIRECTORY"/*
for f in $FILES
do
echo "file $f: "
#ls "$f"
done
```

I'm trying to loop through a file to get each files information to be displayed separately. e.g.

```
first file
name
size
date edited
```

option to go to next file.

```
second file
name
size
date edited
```

and so on, at the moment though it's just displaying this:

```
file/dir/file1
file/dir/file2
```

edit:

right, i've looked into this more and now have this.

```
total=$(find $DIRECTORY -type f | wc -l)
f="1"
while [ $f -lt $total ]
do
echo "file $f: "
stat %n $f
f=$[$f+1]
done
```

what this should do is get the total number of files in the directory, then loop through them. The problem is i don't know how to get the file information to display on them.

```
file 0:
stat: cannot stat ‘%n’: No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat ‘0’: No such file or directory
file 1:
stat: cannot stat ‘%n’: No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat ‘1’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Look into `man stat`

Comment: `$[...]` is obsolete; use `$((...))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the name, size and mtime, try:

```
find "$DIRECTORY" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'stat -c "%n %s %y" "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: Or, if `find` supports `-printf` with all the GNU goodies: `find "$DIRECTORY" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f %s %t\n'`.